# How to get back the intellij settings that are reverted?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I had some Intellij settings and by mistake reverted the settings to default ones. I would like to get my old settings back. Is there a way I can do that ?

Comment: No, unless you are using settings repository or have some manual backup https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html or have Configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory from the older IDE version.